# css button styles wont work using <style> tags with vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Im currently trying to learn vue.js and am trying to add styles to a component. The component itself works, and the functionality (alert message) works aswell but I cant get the styles to implement.

(Now I understand that technically I'm not using vue.js to style in my first example but this is to show what I had tried)

**Attempt 1:**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <input id="test-btn" type="button" v-on:click= clicked()> 
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        name:  'test-btn',
        methods: {
                clicked: function () {
                    alert("Here's your message")

                }
            }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
    #test-btn{
        color: #CC00CC;
        width: 150;
        height: 50;
    }
</style>
```

Though I had changed the color width and height the button remains the generic grey and doesn't change width or height (it just stays a square). but it does work when I click it (at least something works).

Since I couldn't get that to work I tried to use the v-bind method.

**Attempt 2:**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <input id="test-btn" type="button" v-on:click= clicked() v-bind:style="btnStyle"> 
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        name:  'test-btn',
        methods: {
                clicked: function () {
                    alert("Here's your message")
                }
            },
        data: {
            btnStyle: {
                color: 'red',
                width: 100,
                height: 50
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
/*  #test-btn{
        color: #CC00CC;
        width: 150;
        height: 50;
    }*/
</style>
```

This attempt at v-bind also had failed as well. A friend told me that buttons are difficult to make the styling work and it may not be an error with my code, it may be default styling that is over riding it (I cant accept that). So what I did was tried to add `!important`  to my css color line in the script tags but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<button>` is not styled because you have a CSS issue. Add `px` to `width` and `height`. See CSS in the demo below.

The `color` CSS property is the font color. To change the `<button>` color use `background: yellow;`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    clicked: function() {
      alert("Here's your message")
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#test-btn {
  color: #CC00CC;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 150px; /* was 150, now 150px */
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <input id="test-btn" type="button" v-on:click="clicked()" value="Click Me">
  </div>
</div>
```

Works with `data` and `v-bind:style` as well (just do `width: '150px';` and `height: '50px';`). To change the background color add `background: 'yellow'` as well.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    btnStyle: {
      color: '#CC00CC',
      background: 'yellow',
      width: '100px',
      height: '50px'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clicked: function() {
      alert("Here's your message")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <input id="test-btn" type="button" v-on:click="clicked()" v-bind:style="btnStyle" value="CLICK ME">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. clearly I must have missed that. I also am trying to change the color as well but that isn't changing

Comment: The `color` is the font color. To change the button color, use `background: color`. Check the answer, I added some info there and update the demos.